# SoapFault exception: [env:Server] with empty error message

Tags: magento, soap, soap-client

After the soapCall executed in Magento

```
        try {
        $result = $this->__soapCall($this->_soapAction, array());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->logException($e);
        $result = $e;
    }
```

We get the following errors:

```
SoapFault exception: [env:Server]  in /var/www/magento/1.30.1/app/code/local/Sxxxx/Bxxxb/Model/Message/Soap/Abstract.php:297
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento/1.30.1/app/code/local/Sxxxx/Bxxxb/Model/Message/Soap/Abstract.php(297): SoapClient->__soapCall('refundTransacti...', Array)
```

No errors in exceptions and a server exception.
What we tried so far is to pass exceptions = true but the result returns the same. I know that it could be related to a server error but why no message appears ?
Also the communication between server and client correctly happens. We send to the server a request and we get from the server a correct answer, so we don't understand why still an exception is generated.